# Override a delegated event handler for a specific element only in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegation

Consider the following code:

```html
<div id="main">
  <ul>
     <li>
       <span>Normal text</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class="special">Special text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And following JS for above HTML.

```js
(function($) {
  console.clear();
  console.log('hello');

  // (1) main click handler. 
  $(document).on('click', 'span', function(e) {
    console.log('Span :' + e.target.textContent)
  })

  // (2) unbind all the clickhandler on span.
  $(document).off('click', 'span');

  // (3) Override just the .special span click handler.
  $(document).on('click', 'span.special', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Special Item: ' + e.target.textContent)
  })

})(jQuery);
```

Here, the objective is to not run the main click handler (1) on `span.special` click.

If I do (2). which removes all the attached handlers. I want to preserve the main click handler(1) for other spans.

How can I explicitly override the delegated click handler for an individual item?

Thanks in advance.

https://codepen.io/JayKandari/pen/oNjmzBm?editors=1011

**Update:**
If the code in (1) main click handler is coming from another library and cannot be changed directly. How is this possible in this case?

Comment: You can "override" a delegated event with a non-delegated event, but not with another non-delegated as the first will run...well... first https://jsfiddle.net/q07ryLc4/

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different handlers for span without `.special` and spans with it.

To override existing handler you can do so by extracting the handler that was already assigned then turn off handlers for all `spans`. Then assign to each type separately.

Using `.off("click", "span.special")` because `.off()` only works with the exact same selector that `.on()` used.

See this example:

```js
(function($) {
  console.clear();
  console.log('hello');

  $(document).on('click', 'span', function(e) {
    console.log('Span :' + e.target.textContent, e.target);
  });

  // Get all events attached to document to extract handler
  let events = $._data(document, 'events');
  let handler;
  jQuery.each(events['click'], function(type, data) {
    // Check selector to extract handler
    if (data.selector == "span")
      handler = data.handler;
  });

  // unbind all the clickhandler on span.
  $(document).off('click', 'span');

  // Attach to all spans except special
  $(document).on('click', 'span:not(.special)', handler);

  // attach only to special
  $(document).on('click', 'span.special', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Special Item: ' + e.target.textContent)
  })

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Normal text</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="special">Special text</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the answer, I added an update in the question. What if the main click handler cannot be changed? 

Do we have another way of overriding the (1) main click handler?

Comment: It is a bit of a hack but it works. I updated my answer.